# ARP Packet format question

Tags: protocol-theory, arp, rfc

I am unable to understand the meaning behind the following extract from the ARP RFC 826:

> For the 10Mbit Ethernet, the value in the protocol field (ar$pro) is
>   taken from the set ether_type$.  This is a natural reuse of the
>   assigned protocol types.  Combining this with the opcode (ar$op) would
>   effectively halve the number of protocols that can be resolved under
>   this protocol and would make a monitor/debugger more complex (see
>   Network Monitoring and Debugging below).  It is hoped that we will
>   never see 32768 protocols, but Murphy made some laws which don't allow
>   us to make this assumption.

How is this method restricting the protocols that can be resolved to half? The way i see it we can resolve 2^16 protocols using this method.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: I tried to look to see if I could find it but couldn't. I imagine it has to do with one of the bits in the 16-bit field being used for another purpose. That would reduce it to 15-bit field, which would match the 32768. I did see mention of the Op code being inserted into the Protocols field, but later found the opcode had its own dedicated 16 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ARP opcode could be expressed as a single bit (`REQUEST` or `REPLY`).  The argument could be made (and was, at the time) that 16-bits for both `arp$pro` and `arp$op` was wasteful, and that `arp$op` should simply be the high bit of the `arp$pro` field.  Doing this would have restricted the available `arp$pro` space for ethernet to 15-bits.

35 years ago this was a much more significant concern than it is today, and that is why the discussion is called out specifically in the RFC.

Comment: @Rajat If this answer satisfied you, consider marking it as the accepted answer so Nick can get his credit.